# Find the "half projection"

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, projection

A half-projection into a plane is a linear transformation that fixes the plane and moves all other points half way to the plane (instead of all the way, in a standard projection.)

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the (orthogonal) half-projection into the following plane:
>
> $$3x - 3y + 3z = 0$$
>
> Find the matrix of this linear transformation.

That is all that is provided.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I know what an orthogonal projection onto a plane is, but what is an orthogonal half-projection into a plane?

Comment: I updated my post to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! I gave a somewhat more worked out answer but depending on how much linear algebra you've seen up to this point it won't make a lot of sense. If you haven't seen the matrix of a linear map w.r.t. general bases and base change transformations, it's not the answer you are looking for. If that's the case, I'd advise you to return to my answer once you know these concepts. You'll appreciate the beauty of this approach later. Also, once you know eigenvalues and eigenvectors, you'll see that in action as well in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Given $v$, the half projection of $v$ lies exactly halfway between $v$ and the (full) projection of $v$.

Comment: So do I divide each entry in v by 2, and then solve using the projection formula?

Comment: No, the half projection of $v$ is not the projection of half of $v$. That's not what I said.

Comment: Sorry, read that wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the given equation $(3,-3,3)$ is perpendicular to the plane, hence you want to map it to $(\frac32,-\frac32,\frac32)$
By educated guessing, $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$ are in the plane and hence you want to map these to themselves.
Can you find the matrix from these three conditions?

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to hint at but I'm not 100% sure..

Answer (score 0):

Note that the plane $3x-3y+3z=0$ consists of those vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ perpendicular to the normal vector $(3,-3,3)$. Denote by $n$ the normalized normal vector, i.e. $n=\frac{1}{\|(3,-3,3)\|}(3,-3,3)$.

Let $W$ be said plane, you can easily find an orthonormal basis $\left\{w_1,w_2\right\}$ of $W$. By definition $T(w_1)= w_1$ and $T(w_2)=w_2$. Also, by definition $T(n)=\frac{1}{2}n$.

Clearly $\alpha=\left\{n,w_1,w_2 \right\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. this basis is given by $$T_{\alpha}^{\alpha}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} &0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

This is fine, but it's probably not what you want as you want to express the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So all that's left to do is to do a base change which I hope you have seen in your linear algebra course at this point.